# Porting simple form custom inputs to a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, simple-form, materialize

I'm in the process of creating a `simple_form-materialize` gem which will include a configuration generator and custom inputs.

I've created the custom inputs in my application, the problem I am having is porting over these inputs into the gem.
If I simply add them to the gem and try to require them I get `uninitialized constant SimpleForm::Inputs` as the new inputs are inheriting from Base.

So I've now tried to add SimpleForm as a dependancy to the gem and require that but I get
`` undefined method `env' for Rails:Module ``

Using;
Ruby: 2.3.0
Rails: 4.2.0

Diff with code examples: 
https://github.com/patricklindsay/simple_form-materialize/compare/add_inputs?expand=1

Any help would be great as I know this gem will be useful.

Comment: Are you using `isolate_namespace` in your engine? Also, have you required the `simple_form` gem before trying to extend it?

Comment: I'm not using isolate_namespace.. its a gem rather than a engine. Yes tried requiring it, that's what is causing the second error. Check link to github for code examples